# It took a little time because of a great friend

Tags: grammaticality

I want to say that I wanted to quit, but I stayed a little bit longer because of her.

> It took a little time because of a great friend.

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: Please, please, please do not use IM style here. Also, this is an ELL question.

Comment: A great friend is not really the reason: it's their presence. 'I stayed rather longer than I'd planned because I bumped into a great friend there.'

Comment: Is there another formal word instead of stayed? Anyway This is exactly what I expected.Thank you so much....

Answer (score 1):

"It took a little time because of a great friend" is a meaningful sentence, but one that leaves much unsaid. It suggests that *something* about the friend, or something they *did*, caused it to take longer.

I don't know if English speakers of other dialects would say differently, but it's worth throwing in an aside here - "great friend", to me, would generally imply that the person is good at being a friend. "Good friend" could mean either that, or a friend you are particularly close to, and in this context would usually mean one you are close to. "Close friend" obviously means one you are close to, and then there's "old friend", which means someone who has been a friend a long time - with the possible connotation of not seeing them often.

Anyway, to mean what you appear to mean, I would say "I stayed longer than I planned because I ran into a great friend", or "I stayed longer than I planned because there was a great friend there". You say you want something more formal than *stayed*; there is nothing particularly informal about *stay*, but people may read *remain* as more formal or old-fashioned. "I remained longer than I planned..."

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence is ambiguous. Correct, but ambiguous.

> **took a little time** = was fast, needed very little time

What you want to actually say is that you needed a little **more extra** time.

---

> **because of** X = X made me fail

So, it is inappropriate to say:

> I won **because of** my friend.

and is correct to say:

> I won **thanks to** my friend.

---

Actually, your friend did nothing, so the extra time needed is not related to the friend, but to your own decision - related to the friend.

Bottom line, the following will say the same, but less ambiguous:

> It took a little bit longer than anticipated because I met with a great friend.

or even:

> I stayed a little bit longer than anticipated because I met with a great friend.